# how to catch NULL values using case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

here in this query I want to replace the values in Person.Contact of Adventureworks database with some new values. The below query case statement is working fine for other values but I am not able to change the values those are in NULL. I am using SQL Server. Any help is appreciated.

```
select contactid,Title,FirstName,MiddleName,
case MiddleName
when 'R.' then 'Robert'
when 'B.' then 'Bids'
when 'J.' then 'John'
when is null then 'New Name'
else 'No Name'
end, LastName from Person.Contact
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'd use the ISNULL function - it will return the value given if the field is NULL:

```
select contactid,Title,FirstName,MiddleName,
case ISNULL(MiddleName, 'NULLVALUE')
when 'R.' then 'Robert'
when 'B.' then 'Bids'
when 'J.' then 'John'
when 'NULLVALUE' then 'New Name'
else 'No Name'
end, LastName from Person.Contact
```

Comment: I agree. Let's  just hope that nobody has 'NULLVALUE' as middle name.

Comment: Is that like little Bobby DROP TABLES?

Comment: @JohnDunagan Well, our is less dangerous

Comment: For anyone interested in the story of bobby tables: [Here you are](https://xkcd.com/327/).

Answer (score 16):

```
case 
when MiddleName is null then ...
when MiddleName = 'R' then ...
end
```

Answer (score 5):

Sorry to post 7 years later, but I've been trying to find a solution for Interbase / Firebird and this post kept popping up. None of the solutions here work because there is no ISNULL, so I figured I'd help anyone else who might come here looking for that:

```
select contactid,Title,FirstName,MiddleName,
case COALESCE(MiddleName, 'NULLVALUE')
when 'R.' then 'Robert'
when 'B.' then 'Bids'
when 'J.' then 'John'
when 'NULLVALUE' then 'New Name'
else 'No Name'
end, LastName from Person.Contact
```

Comment: Firebird does not have [`is null`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2085129/11683) too (as opposed to `isnull`)?

Comment: Thank you very much.. Had the same trouble with using Interbase that doesn't have ISNULL but your code worked!

Comment: @GSerg Firebird might, but I was working in InterBase... Firebird seems to have more features, but anything that works in InterBase should work in Firebird, but not the other way around.

Also, I saw all kinds of links to setup your own UDF for ISNULL, but that seemed a bit beyond what I was needing to do.