# How to check for NULL in a CASE statement with a Scalar Function?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How do you check for `NULL` in a `CASE` statement, when you're using a `Scalar Function`?

My original query was ... but it fails

```
SELECT  CASE dbo.fnCarerResponse('')
          WHEN NULL THEN 'Pass'
          ELSE 'Fail'
        END
```

I read the [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2085100/how-to-catch-null-values-using-case-statement) question about using `IS NULL`, like so ...

```
SELECT  CASE dbo.fnCarerResponse('') IS NULL 
          WHEN NULL THEN 'Pass'
          ELSE 'Fail'
        END
```

but this gives the `incorrect syntax near the keyword is` error

Can you have a `Scalar Function` in the `CASE` ?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You are using the wrong style of `CASE` - you need to use `CASE WHEN <expression> THEN` not `CASE <expression> WHEN <expression> then`:

```
SELECT CASE 
 WHEN dbo.fnCarerResponse('') IS NULL
 THEN 'Pass'
 ELSE 'Fail'
END
```

Answer (score 9):

```
SELECT CASE 
         WHEN dbo.fnCarerResponse('') IS NULL 
         THEN 'Pass'
         ELSE 'Fail'
       END
```

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT  CASE 
          WHEN dbo.fnCarerResponse('') is NULL THEN 'Pass'
          ELSE 'Fail'
        END
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this way too:

```
SELECT   CASE ISNULL(dbo.fnCarerResponse(''),'NULLVALUE')
           WHEN 'NULLVALUE' THEN 'Pass'
           ELSE 'Fail'
         END
```

Answer (score 0):

When used in the context of a list, such as the definitions of the columns of a SELECT query, the entire expression must be wrapped in parentheses, like this.

```
     ,LastEditorEmail = (SELECT CASE
        WHEN  CF.LastModifiedBy IS NULL THEN
            NULL
        ELSE
            UE.Email
    END)
```